# View historical data per IP with PRTG packet sniffer

Tags: networking, bandwidth, packet-sniffer

I have recently set up PRTG's packet sniffer sensor for bandwidth monitoring. I am able to pull up historical data in 15 minute increments and see who was the highest user but I would like to see which IP was the highest user over, say, 48 hours.

As far as I can tell, I am only able to see overall bandwidth usage for anything more than 15 minute increments and not per IP usage. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I haven't use a version of PRTG more current then version 6 and I don't have one handy but I'm fairly certain you can change how long the data is saved for in the properties of the sensor or the properties of the sensor graph. Take a look at that and see if it points you in the right direction.

Comment: I'm still playing with it but I did setup a custom graph and set to to 48 hours instead of the default 15 minutes. It still defaulted back to 15 minutes though